# How do I generate multiple plots from grouped data using Matplotlib or Seaborn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

[image: Dataframe]

It is grouped/indexed by the age range of the participants in the data set. For each age range in the dataframe, I'd like to generate a barplot whose bars display the rates of divorce, marriage, etc. for that particular age range. How can I do this using either matplotlib or seaborn? Thanks in advance for any assistance rendered.

Code used to generate the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age_range': [(18, 28), (28, 38), (38, 48), (48, 58), (58, 68), (68, 78), (78, 88)],
    'divorced': [0.015837, 0.068826, 0.138132, 0.185022, 0.180258, 0.179211, 0.099502],
    'living with partner': [0.21040724, 0.14979757, 0.07392996, 0.06828194, 0.04506438, 0.01075269, 0.00995025],
    'married': [0.24208145, 0.51619433, 0.57198444, 0.54625551, 0.50429185, 0.37992832, 0.28855721],
    'never_married': [0.50904977, 0.23279352, 0.14202335, 0.08370044, 0.09012876,0.05734767, 0.05472637],
    'refused': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0.00214592, np.nan, np.nan],
    'widowed': [np.nan, 0.00202429, 0.0155642 , 0.05506608, 0.12875536, 0.33691756, 0.53731343]
})

df.set_index('age_range', inplace=True)
df
```

Comment: it's very much possible. there are many ways to do it. you need to be more specific about what kind of bar plot you would like (e.g., faceted, stacked....). You should also include your dataframe in a copy-pastable format

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I updated the post with the code for the dataframe in a copy-pastable format. I'd like it faceted.

Comment: Simply `df.plot.bar()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these percentages tend to add up to 1, a stacked bar chart is rather suitable:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
ax = df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

Result:

[image: stacked bar chart of marriage status]

Answer (score 0):

If you *don't* want stacked bars and do want it faceted by hue, this is pretty quick with seaborn:

```py
g = (
    df.stack()
      .to_frame('Count')
      .rename_axis(index=['Age Range', 'Status'])
      .reset_index()
      .pipe((sns.factorplot, 'data'), 
            x='Age Range', y='Count',
            hue='Status', kind='bar',
            size=3.5, aspect=1.86)

)
```

[image]

Or you can facet by columns:

```py
g = (
    df.stack()
      .to_frame('Count')
      .rename_axis(index=['Age Range', 'Status'])
      .reset_index()
      .pipe((sns.factorplot, 'data'), 
            x='Age Range', y='Count',
            col='Status', kind='bar',
            size=3.5, aspect=1.86, col_wrap=2)

)
```

[image]